# Change Timezone of Database on the time of connection in ActiveRecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

is there any way in [ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) for changing the timezone of database dynamically on the time of connection .

i am using it with codeigniter . problem is that i change the timezone in codeigniter successfully, but it don't effects on ActiveRecord queries.

thanks in advance .

Comment: Is that you are looking for `$this->db->query("SET SESSION time_zone = 'your timezone'")`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes and i use it but it not effects on ActiveRecord queries.

Comment: How it is possible,it is changing the timezone for mysql's session it should work

Comment: sorry but not work on ActiveRecord queries.

Answer (score 1):

Set a default Timezone(index.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Set DateTime Format Manually in the Model

```
static $datetime_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

Also, try adding this to your initialize file(im guessing you used sparks to install php-activerecord)

```
    //Include the ActiveRecord DateTime Class
    require_once $spark_path.'vendor/php-activerecord/lib/DateTime.php';
    
    //it should use your database time format, once you set it.
    ActiveRecord\DateTime::$DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'db';
```

Comment: It will set php timezone. i need to set timezone for MySQL database on per connection.

Comment: Does php-activerecord have an initialize method/file?

Comment: yes it has but i don't know how to set timezone there and could not find on phpactiverecord site.

Comment: @Philips my issue is not (DateTime Format). in my application i need to show time according to users timezone. in database default timezone is UTC.